# Postback in parent with Fancybox

Tags: jquery, asp.net, fancybox-2

I've been doing some tests with the fancybox and what I we really need here at work is some kind of modal that after it's closed it does a postback in the parent page. I'm trying to make it with fancybox, I've read other topics and tried doing it this way, but it doesn't work, it doesn't even enter in the event since the alert doesn't show up:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".various").fancybox({
            modal: true,
            fitToView: true,
            width: 800,
            height: 500,
            autoSize: false,
            closeClick: false,
            openEffect: 'fade',
            closeEffect: 'fade',
            onClose: function () {
                alert("Hello");
                parent.location.reload(true);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

I've also tried doing it with `__doPostBack()` but didn't worked either. Can someone help me?

Comment: Your callback is wrong. Try `afterClose`.

Comment: Tried it, but still no postback, the alert shows up, so now I know it enters the function at least

Comment: Managed to do it now, thanks for the help, the postback was there but my test had almost no controls in it so the reload wasn't noticied by me until I added a string with the `DateTime.Now`

Comment: actually the correct answer was from @Nix

Comment: Number #14 from fancyapps.com/fancybox/#useful

Comment: Please unnaccept my accepted (but incorrect) answer and I will delete it.  You can accept the answer from @Nix which is correct for fancybox 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your callback is wrong. Try `afterClose`.